# FormState is not updating immedietly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a form with two inputs. One is a dropwdown with Yes/No value. other is a text.
My requirement is follwoing -
if Yes is seleceted in dropdwon then text should become manadatory.
If No is selected then it should not be mandatory to fill.
then problem I am facing with the code is that when i select Yes in the dropdown and set it in formstate, i want to use it to set a variable showHide which can be used in text field's mandatory/non mandorty requirement. but formstate does not update immediatly.

```
const [Info,setInfo] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
const haveInfoData = [
{label: 'Yes', value : 'Yes'},
{label: 'No', value : 'No'}
];
sethaveInfoData(haveInfoData);
}
, []);
```

```
<FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel className="required-field">{retrieveLanguage(language, 'info')}</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl
        name="info"
        accepter={SelectPicker}
        data={haveInfoData}
        errorMessage={errorState.haveInfoError}
        value={formState.info}
        onChange={(e) => setFormState({ ...formState, info: e })}
        onBlur={(e) => handleShowHide("info", e.target.value)}
    />
</FormGroup>
```

```
<FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel className={showHide ? "required-field" : ""}>{retrieveLanguage(language, 'Number')}</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl name="Number"
        errorMessage={errorState.NumberError}
        value={formState.Number}
        onBlur={(e) => onFieldChange("Number", e.target.value)}
        onChange={(e) => setFormState({ ...formState, Number: e })} />
</FormGroup>
```

```
const handleShowHide=(fieldName,e)=>{
                          let stateObj = { ...formState };
                                  stateObj[fieldName] = e;
                                  setFormState(stateObj);
                                  let nextErrorState = { ...errorState };
                                  const validationResult = validatePersonalDetails(fieldName, e, formState, language)
                                  nextErrorState[fieldName + "Error"] = validationResult.error;
                                  setErrorState(nextErrorState);
                                  if(formState.Info==='Yes'){
                                      setShowHide(true);
                                      console.log("showHideOnYes: "+showHide);
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      setShowHide(false);
                                      console.log("showHideOnNo: "+showHide);
                                  }
                      }
```

I am not able to understan what i am missing here.

On select on Yes/No values another text field's required status should change.

Comment: Add code in Codesandbox for debugging is better